# How to get a dict from a list of dict according to some threshold

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of dicts like the one below:

```
list_dict = [{'Name': 'Andres', 'score': 0.17669814825057983},
 {'Name': 'Paul', 'score': 0.14028045535087585},
 {'Name': 'Feder', 'score': 0.1379694938659668},
 {'Name': 'James', 'score': 0.1348174512386322}]
```

I want to output another **list of dict** but only when sum of score is higher than a `threshold=0.15`

Expected output: `[{'name':'Andres', 'score' : 0.1766..}]`

I did this, but the code is terrible and the outuput is wrongly formatted

```
l = []
for i in range(len(list_dict)):
    for k in list_dict[i]['name']:
        if list_dict[i]['score']>0.15:
            print(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking?

Actually you're very *close*... but just miss a few syntax.
Each item in list_dict is a dictionary, so you can access and ask the *score*, it should not use *index* to get the interesting part.

```
new_dc = list()

for item in list_dict:            # each item is a dictionary
    if item['score'] > 0.15:      # it's better to use a meaningful variable. 
        new_dc.append(item)
        
print(new_dc)                    # [{'Name': 'Andres', 'score': 0.17669814825057983}]
```

#### Alternatively you can use List Comprehension:

```
output = [item for item in list_dict if item['score'] > 0.15]

assert new_dc == output    # Silence mean they're the same
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st approach using loop**

```
final_list = []
for each in list_dict: #simply iterate through each dict in list and compare score
    if each['score']>0.15:
        final_list.append(each)
print(final_list)
```

**2nd approach using list comprehension**

```
final_list = [item for item in list_dict if item['score']>0.15]
print(final_list)
```